# How remove part of url from browser with htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I have 2 domains in the same hosting, inside the folder public_html stay the folders and the index.php from the domain principal and inside the public_html have other folder with the name "domain2.com" where have the index.php from [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)

Actually if enter to [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) or [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) function perfectly but if i need enter in [www.domain2.com/folder2](http://www.domain2.com/folder2) dont work for enter in folder "folder2" need put the domain this way [www.domain2.com/domain2.com/whereber](http://www.domain2.com/domain2.com/whereber) and this way works

My question is how do I modify the .htacces file so that when entering [www.domain2.com/domain2.com/folder2](http://www.domain2.com/domain2.com/folder2) it only shows the address [www.domain2.com/folder](http://www.domain2.com/folder)

This is my code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.com.ar$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1.com.ar/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1.com.ar/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com.ar$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain2.com.ar/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I currently use a shared hosting with php 5.6

Thank you very much and excuse my english

Comment: Rather than trying to solve this problem in .htaccess I recommend changing the `DocumentRoot` in the Apache conf files.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The OP wrote that a "hosting" is used. So most likely no access to the actual http server's configuration exists.

Comment: @arkascha There are lots of types of hosting including cloud hosting and VPS that give you full control over your servers.  Even with shared hosting, there is often control over document roots via add-on domains or other configuration via the web interface given to you by your hosting company.

Comment: unfortly my have shared hosting and not have a configuration via the web interface. My only option is modify the file .htacess

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be in your site's root directory configuration.

Basically now it means that your site's files are located in server's `root/domain2.com/`.

In a simple words, your domain is connected to a root folder which contains another folder called `domain2.com` and looks like `domain2.com` contains your site files.

So in order to fix this, try to locate folder `domain2.com` in your server and move all files from `domain2.com` to folder where `domain2.com` was located.

Could you please specify what server are you using? Are you using shared hosting like ***cPanel*** or ***Plesk*** or you are using vps/dedicated like ***iis windows server***?

Comment: unfortly my have shared hosting and not have a configuration via the web interface. My only option is modify the file .htacess